# How to upload file in jsf using primefaces <p:confirm/>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi am trying to upload a file using primefaces which works fine when I don't have confirm dialog in the submit button. but when I add the  the managed bean is not even called.

Here is my xhtml code:

```
<p:panel header="New Business Registration" style=" min-height: 400px"> 

    <h:form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:messages closable="true" />
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Select Image"/>
           <p:fileUpload mode="simple" value="#{fileUploadMBean.uploadedFile}"/>
          p:outputLabel value=""/>
          <p:commandButton  update="upload" ajax="false" action="#{fileUploadMBean.uploadFile}" icon="ui-icon-person" value="Register New Client">
                <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure you wish to upload this file" />
         </p:commandButton>
          </p:panelGrid>
     </h:form>   
    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" style="color: #fff;
                                 background-color: #5cb85c;
                                 border-color: #4cae4c;" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon=" ui-icon-check" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" style="background-color: #d9534f;  border-color: #d43f3a;" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-closethick" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
 </p:panel>
```

And my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileUploadMBean implements Serializable {
      private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
public String uploadFile() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("hello:"); //method not called when i use confirm dialog but when i dont use file upload is successfull
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            if(uploadedFile==null)
            {

                        context.addMessnage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Blank File detected", "image"));
                return "";
            }
            //jsf file upload here
            {}//upload code here which works fine without p:confirm

            return null;
            }
```

When I use

```
<p:commandButton update="upload" action="#{fileUploadMBean.uploadFile}" icon="ui-icon-person" value="Register New Client">


      </p:commandButton>
```

The uploaded file is null;

When I disable Ajax and without  like

```
<p:commandButton update="upload" action="#{fileUploadMBean.uploadFile}" icon="ui-icon-person" ajax="false" value="Register New Client">


      </p:commandButton>
```

Upload is Successfull.

When I now add  when ajax is disabled in the submit button the managed method is not getting invoked at all

```
 <p:commandButton update="upload" action="#{fileUploadMBean.uploadFile}" icon="ui-icon-person" ajax="false" value="Register New Client">

          <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure you wish to upload this file" />
          </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Start by checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value (and sessionscoped is imo too long for this kind of service) And state your JSF version and implementation and PrimeFaces

Comment: According to the showcase (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml) you shoud alse have a `<p:confirmDialog />`

Comment: @OscarPérez I have re-edited the question and the error is still there

Comment: @Kukeltje I need to have a session scoped to store information of the user who logged in the system

Comment: Sure, we do too and store **that** in a session scoped bean. That does not mean we use the same session scoped bean to act as a backingbean for uploads. Bad design. Viewscoped is sufficient, often requestscoped

Comment: And what is 'the error'? And does it all work when replacing the fileUpload with an inputext?

Comment: Does the broser's javascript console show any messages? And the server output? Did you inspected XHR connections?

Comment: @Kukeltje There is no error the fact that the managed bean method is not even called. I have tried even ViewScoped and the method is not getting invoked

Comment: @OscarPérez There is no error in browser console

Comment: Then create a [mcve] and post version info please and try with an inputtext, no enctype and with and without ajax

Comment: @Kukeltje Kindly Check I have re-edited the question and still stuck. Kindly help

Comment: where is the confirm in the ajax enabled one? And the one with and without ajax but with an inputText? I suspect confirm does not work without ajax. Andhat is your pf version? Tried the latest?

Comment: @Kukeltje Am using primefaces 5.3. If confirm does not work without ajax what could be workaround to ensure the user need to be notified of the action before committing changes?

Comment: What about a plain old javascript's `confirm()` ?

Comment: **I'm not saying it does not work, I'm suggesting to TEST and see if it is related to not using ajax** And there was another remark to TRY the latest (if it is a problem without ajax and plain inputs)**. TRY things instead of directly asking new questions... Only if in the end it is just a problem when not using ajax, we can investigate. And @OscarPerez made me thing in another direction, you can also use the javascript opening of a confirm dialog. See the documentation

Comment: @BalusC kindly assist on this

Comment: @Oscar Pérez  javascripts confirm not working when ajax is disabled in jsf

Comment: @Kukeltje Have you tried running that code you see the problem am facing

Comment: No I did not yet, since you did not try with plain input, there is **no [mcve] and you did not try with a latest verision. And 'begging' for help is (like mentioned before) not appreciated. Cheers....

Comment: Javascript's `confirm()` does work. You can add in your `commandButton` something like: `onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false;}"`